# Strange symbols instead of normal icons and sidekiq issue in GitLab

Tags: git, web, icons, url

After setting the relative url in gitlab:

```
# Note that three settings need to be changed for this to work.
# 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
# 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
# 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
```

I can access my gitlab via dyndns. (like https://my_subdomain.dyndns.com/gitlab).

But...

Instead of normal icons I get strange china-styled ones:

[image]

Sidekiq has problems in displaying, too. I have `nginx` running.
I followed the official guide.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer -.-

```
$ sudo -u git -H vim config/application.rb
```

Uncomment the line nr: 73

Change assets version in line nr: 69

```
config.assets.version = '1.0.1'
```

Update assets:

```
$ sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Restart gitlab:

```
$ sudo service gitlab restart
```

[Please read!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)

> https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/4670

(If someone has the same problems)

Comment: Whilst this answers your question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: will edit it later, sorry